# 3 columns fluid flexbox and rtl

Tags: html, css, flexbox, direction

I have 3 fluid columns, in direction ltr, they go left to right which I want, but on direction rtl, they reverse order which I would like to prevent. Is there a way to prevent order reverse without specifying direction: ltr on container element? (because then container children inherit this behavior which I dont want)

```css
#container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  direction:rtl;/* just for presentation, this would be on html element */
}

#leftcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#centercol {
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining horizontal space */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#rightcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftcol">
    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>
    <div class="box">c</div>
  </div>
  <div id="centercol">
    center
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: care to expain why you changed the accepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just put `flex-direction: row-reverse` instead of `direction: ltr` on container element.

```css
#container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  direction:rtl;/* just for presentation, this would be on html element */
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#leftcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#centercol {
  flex: 1; /* takes the remaining horizontal space */
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#rightcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftcol">
    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>
    <div class="box">c</div>
  </div>
  <div id="centercol">
    center
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what OP want

Comment: I thought he was using (and must use) direction for language purposes (i.e. Arabic content), not presentational purposes. So I kept direction and used only the "column-reverse" (which should be row-reverse, my mistake) property to change the columns order.

Comment: But if hte container (or parent) doesn't have RTL, then the columns would reverse.  it would be better to use `[dir="rtl"] #container { flex-direction: row-reverse; }` to target only when the page has an element with attribute `dir="rtl"` as an ancestor.

Answer (score 2):

> I have 3 fluid columns, in direction ltr, they go left to right which
>   I want, but on direction rtl, they reverse order which I would like to
>   prevent.

- You have to use `flex-direction: row-reverse` in `#container`

> Is there a way to prevent order reverse without specifying direction:
>   ltr on container element? (because then container children inherit
>   this behavior which I dont want)

- You have to use `flex-direction: row-reverse` in `#container>div` (direct children of `#container`)

```css
html {
  direction: rtl;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

#leftcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#centercol {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#rightcol {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#container>div {
  /* to avoid float:left in .box */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftcol">
    <div class="box">a</div>
    <div class="box">b</div>
    <div class="box">c</div>
  </div>
  <div id="centercol">
    center
  </div>
  <div id="rightcol">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```